# Getting wrong result while doing case insensitive search

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a xml documents in MarkLogic,

Document 1 -
URI - /test1/wf1

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow>
    <workflowName>Oracle_RMS_9_RMS_9_Pos_and_Allocations_WF</workflowName>
    <workflowDescription>
    </workflowDescription>
    <endPointName>Oracle RMS 9_RMS 9 Pos and Allocations</endPointName>
    <createdDttm>2019-06-11 00:21:26.2121Z</createdDttm>
    <modifiedDttm>2019-08-28T04:37:19.764Z</modifiedDttm>
</workflow>
```

My requirement is to get the document uris only if element value matches with ignore case.

```
cts:uris((),(),cts:and-query((cts:collection-query("workflow"),cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("endPointName"),"Oracle RMS 9 RMS 9 POs and Allocations",("case-insensitive","whitespace-sensitive")))))
```

I am executing above query to get the document URI matching  value with `xs:QName("endPointName")` here I am expecting empty sequence because there is no matching document but I am getting /test/wf1 as query result.

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "exact" option in the query with case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive. This might resolve the issue.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Documentation can be found here : https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query

Comment: Thanks @Ishaan for your response. I already tried using "exact" and i got this error `[1.0-ml] XDMP-INCONSOPTS: cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","endPointName"), "Oracle RMS 9 RMS 9 POs and Allocations", ("exact", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive")) -- Inconsistent options exact case-insensitive`

Comment: "exact" will be case-sensitive so this will not fulfill his requirement of ignoring case.

Comment: Also, he's using element-value-query not element-word-query

Comment: I think need to think about a way to exclude underscore's then. Thinking about it.

Comment: Use 'exact' alone. Exact is shorthand for "case-sensitive", "diacritic-sensitive", "punctuation-sensitive", "whitespace-sensitive", "unstemmed", and "unwildcarded".  Also see: https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/476/0/understanding-search-value-queries

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query#options) on cts:element-value-query :

> If neither "punctuation-sensitive" nor "punctuation-insensitive" is
>   present, $text is used to determine punctuation sensitivity. If $text
>   contains no punctuation, it specifies "punctuation-insensitive". If
>   $text contains punctuation, it specifies "punctuation-sensitive".

I expect you need to specify the option "punctuation-sensitive" since there is no punctuation in your search string.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i added `punctuation-sensitive` but still i am getting same behavior. now my options are `("punctuation-insensitive", "case-insensitive","whitespace-sensitive")`.

Comment: @ShivlingBhandare Try going whitespace-insensitive. Perhaps that's tripping you up

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried but still getting same result.

Comment: @ShivlingBhandare, you speak of `("punctuation-insensitive", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive")` in your first comment, but that is the wrong punctuation option. You really need punctuation-sensitive, case-insensitive, and whitespace-sensitive here. As alternative, you could use a range index with a collation that ignores case.

Comment: @grtjn, Can you please give sample snippet using range index with a collation which will fulfill my requirement.

Comment: You'd need an element range index on the element `endPointName` of type `string` with collation `http://marklogic.com/collation//S1` or `http://marklogic.com/collation//S2`. Use the `collation builder` button when adding the index to understand what options there are.